# Set conditions on ImageUrl in HyperLink tag

Tags: c#, gridview, hyperlink, imageurl

I need to show in my `GridView` different icons when respected determined conditions.

These conditions they are relative on the fields :

```
1) SendEmail; 
2) SendData.
```

If `SendEmail` and `SendData` are null or empty I need to show the image `email-grey.gif`

If `SendEmail` is not null and `SendData` is null I need to show the image `email-orange.gif`

If `SendData` is not null I need to show the image `email-open-grey.gif`

I have tried this solution without success,

```
ImageUrl='<%#(String.IsNullOrEmpty("SendEmail") ? String.IsNullOrEmpty("SendData") ? "/Images/Mini_Pixel_Icons/email-grey.gif" : "/Images/Mini_Pixel_Icons/email-open-grey.gif" : String.IsNullOrEmpty("SendData") ? "/Images/Mini_Pixel_Icons/email-open-orange.gif" : "/Images/Mini_Pixel_Icons/email-open-grey.gif")%>'
```

because all rows they are in the condition :

```
/Images/Mini_Pixel_Icons/email-open-grey.gif
```

Please help me, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ImageUrl='<%# String.Format("{0}",
(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("SendEmail").ToString()) &
String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("SendData").ToString())) ? "email-grey.gif" : 
(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("SendEmail").ToString()) & 
String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("SendData").ToString()) ) ? "email-orange.gif" :
(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("SendData").ToString())) ? "email-open-grey.gif" : 
"")%>'
```